# Is it guaranteed that only one callback is executed when the wait condition is true?

Tags: abap

This is regarding the statement `WAIT FOR ASYNCHRONOUS TASKS` and the corresponding part of the documentation:

> If the result of log_exp is false and there is an asynchronous function call with callback routine, the program waits until a callback routine of a previous function (called asynchronously) has been executed and then checks the logical expression again:

Let's say I spawn 4 tasks, each reducing `availability` attribute by one, reaching 0. In the callback, they increase the `availability` attribute by one.
Now when I reach `WAIT FOR ASYNCHRONOUS TASKS UNTIL availability > 0 UP TO 6000 SECONDS.` the program waits until the counter is increased by a callback.

Question: When the logical expression is checked again, is it guaranteed that the order is

`callback->check->callback->check`?

Or could it be that `availability` is e.g. already 3, since it did

`callback->callback->callback->check`?

Comment: It's how `WAIT` works and how it is documented. Maybe I don't get your question?

Comment: @SandraRossi The documentation says `wait until a callback has been executed`. Technically this is also true when more than one callback was executed.

Comment: Could you please add a [mre]? I'm not sure I understand the question ...

Comment: Every time the callback is executed, the kernel will check the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as per documentation.

WAIT ->  CALLBACK -> CHECK , WAIT -> CALLBACK -> CHECK,
until wait condition is true or no more outstanding Callbacks are open.

It is important that the Callback form/method has finished before the check is performed as that routine is responsible for changing the variable/s in the WAIT UNTIL Condition.

An extract from the docu.

> If the result of log_exp is false and there is an asynchronous
> function call with callback routine, the program waits until a
> callback routine of a previous function (called asynchronously) has
> been executed and then checks the logical expression again:

If you are concerned about 2 callbacks occurring concurrently,
the callbacks are handled by the kernel  sequentially.
There is no guarantee of order, just that the call backs are processed sequentially.  Note the waiting program is only executed in 1 Work process at a time. From my tests, it is always the same Work process.

Comment: So there’s no way that multiple callbacks finish before the wait is checked again? So assuming I always want 5 parallel tasks and do that with the increment and decrement, I can always assume that the wait check will be executed after one finished. So the counter will be 4 and never 3 or less (given i increment when starting and decrement in callback)

Comment: "So there’s no way that multiple callbacks finish before the wait is checked again? "  that's  right.  The matter of only wanting 5 parallel is another discussion. You should let the server manage that as a maximum.   Next question time

Comment: I'm using GROUP DEFAULT, so it can run anywhere. Yet firing 100 tasks to that group seems a bit wasteful. And I dont want someone to maintain a group in every system